# System::String has no member Length in C++/CLI

Tags: string, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm developing a DLL that connects C++ with C# code, using C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2017. For the project I enabled the complier option '/clr' in `Project -> Properties -> General`. I created a `String^` variable that for which I would like to read its length, yet I am unable to do so, since the IntelliSense cannot find the property `Length`, while most of the other `System::String` functions are available, like `Clone, Compare, CompareOrdinal` etc.

In the pseudo-code example below, I would like to copy a `String` to a buffer, but truncate if its length exceeds some limit.

```
void copyToBuffer(String^ message, char* f_buffer)
{
   if(message->Length > some limit)
      truncate...

   copy to buffer...
}
```

The compilation fails because the compiler throws an error of `class "System::String" has no member "Length"`, even though I can easily navigate to the `Length` property in the Object Browser.

[Length is listed in the Object Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGjSp.png)

What's missing?

Comment: What's missing is the _actual_ code that is producing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the project build property from "/permissive-" to "/permissive"
After I did this in a test, the Length property appears useful.

Comment: I saw your answer too late, I managed to solve the issue just as you mentioned here. Thanks!